# Get item with key as a variable

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3prop

I am trying to retrieve a value of a specified key which is stored in a variable. Normally we would use Nx to expand the variable but `\prop_item:Nx`throws an error. How do I retrieve the value if the key is a variable?

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 Value: \prop_item:Nx
                          \l__dict_prop {\tl_use:N \l__key_str}
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A property list was misused.
```

MWE:

```tex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nx } % Added
\prop_new:N \l__dict_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l__dict_prop {1} {First}
Value: \prop_item:Nn \l__dict_prop {1} % Works fine
\\
\str_set:Nn \l__key_str {1}
Key: \str_use:N \l__key_str % Works fine
\\
Value: \prop_item:Nn \l__dict_prop {\str_use:N \l__key_str} % Works with added first line

%\str_set:Nx \l__value {\prop_item:Nx \l__dict_prop {\str_use:N \l__key_str}} % Not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variants are not pre-defined, so you have to define them yourself with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nx }
```

then

```
Value: \prop_item:Nx \l__dict_prop { \str_use:N \l__key_str }
```

will work.

In this case, since you are taking the value of a variable, you can use the `V` variant as well, so

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { NV }
```

and then

```
Value: \prop_item:NV \l__dict_prop \l__key_str
```

---

Regarding your edit: you tried to do:

```latex
\str_set:Nx \l__value_str { \prop_item:Nx \l__dict_prop { \str_use:N \l__key_str } }
```

however that will not work because commands that use `x` expansion are not expandable.  That is, you cannot nest a command with an `x` argument in another `x` argument like you did above.  Section [**5.3 Introducing the variants**](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#section.5.3) of `interface3` explains the different expansion types, but in short only the `x` type cannot be nested because it is not expandable.

You can either use an expandable variant: here `V` or `e` would work (assuming you already defined them with `\cs_generated_variant:Nn` as explained above):

```latex
\str_set:Nx \l__value_str { \prop_item:Ne \l__dict_prop { \str_use:N \l__key_str } }
% or
\str_set:Nx \l__value_str { \prop_item:NV \l__dict_prop \l__key_str }
```

or you can use `\prop_get:NnN` (the with the `:NVN` variant here):

```latex
\prop_get:NVN \l__dict_prop \l__key_str \l__value_str
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will be very happy if you could answer my second question. I added a new line (commented out) that is not working for some reason. Why does it throws the same error?

Comment: @Nyanyan I edited my answer.  Please pay attention to the naming of variables:  a variable name like `\l__value` is bad because it doesn't include the variable type: it should be `\l__value_str` or, better yet, `\l__mypkg_value_str`, where `mypkg` is the name of your package/class/module (it acts like a namespace).

Comment: Thanks again and sorry, I forgot to include the type :/

Comment: @Nyanyan Oh, no need to apologise, my job is to be a nuisance regarding conventions :)